# Displaying cloudmade tiles in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, openlayers-2, cloudmade

I have created a number of cloudmade maps which I use in my opensource webstack using OpenLayers.

I have been asked if the `cloudmade maps` could also be shown in ArcMap 9 or 10, but have not seen any way to be able to do this?

Does anyone know if this is possible with a normal ArcGIS Desktop (ArcView) licence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can  load Cloudmade tiles into ArcGIS 10 by using ArcBrutile.
This open source extension comes with some map tile services of which Cloudmade is one.
You can see the xml config file of CloudMade with 3 styles at this [[link]](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9984329/ArcBruTile/Services/Cloudmade/Cloudmade.xml)

```
<TileMap

  title="Midnight Commander"

  srs="EPSG:4326"

  type="InvertedTMS"

  profile="local"

  href="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9984329/ArcBruTile/Services/Cloudmade/Midnight Commander.xml" />

<TileMap

  title="Pale Dawn"

  srs="EPSG:4326"

  type="InvertedTMS"

  profile="local"

  href="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9984329/ArcBruTile/Services/Cloudmade/Pale Dawn.xml" />

<TileMap

  title="Fresh"

  srs="EPSG:4326"

  type="InvertedTMS"

  profile="local"

  href="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9984329/ArcBruTile/Services/Cloudmade/Fresh.xml" />
```

Opening one of those style links, you can see more details about configuration of the style, e.g Pale Dawn

```
          <Title>OSM_New_cache</Title>

          <Abstract></Abstract>

          <SRS>EPSG:4326</SRS>

          <BoundingBox minx="-180.000000" miny="-90.000000" maxx="180.000000" maxy="90.000000" />

          <Origin x="-180.000000" y="-90.000000" />  

          <TileFormat width="256" height="256" mime-type="image/png" extension="png" />

          <TileSets>



             <TileSet href="http://c.tile.cloudmade.com/BC9A493B41014CAABB98F0471D759707/998/256/0"

                      units-per-pixel="0.70312500000000000000" order="0" />

             <TileSet href="http://c.tile.cloudmade.com/BC9A493B41014CAABB98F0471D759707/998/256/1"

                      units-per-pixel="0.35156250000000000000" order="1" />

             <TileSet href="http://c.tile.cloudmade.com/BC9A493B41014CAABB98F0471D759707/998/256/2"

                      units-per-pixel="0.17578125000000000000" order="2" />

             <TileSet href="http://c.tile.cloudmade.com/BC9A493B41014CAABB98F0471D759707/998/256/3"

                      units-per-pixel="0.08789062500000000000" order="3" />

             <TileSet href="http://c.tile.cloudmade.com/BC9A493B41014CAABB98F0471D759707/998/256/4"

                      units-per-pixel="0.04394531250000000000" order="4" />

             <TileSet href="http://c.tile.cloudmade.com/BC9A493B41014CAABB98F0471D759707/998/256/5"

                      units-per-pixel="0.02197265625000000000" order="5" />

             <TileSet href="http://c.tile.cloudmade.com/BC9A493B41014CAABB98F0471D759707/998/256/6"

                      units-per-pixel="0.01098632812500000000" order="6" />

             <TileSet href="http://c.tile.cloudmade.com/BC9A493B41014CAABB98F0471D759707/998/256/7"

                      units-per-pixel="0.00549316406250000000" order="7" />

             <TileSet href="http://c.tile.cloudmade.com/BC9A493B41014CAABB98F0471D759707/998/256/8"

                      units-per-pixel="0.00274658203125000000" order="8" />

             <TileSet href="http://c.tile.cloudmade.com/BC9A493B41014CAABB98F0471D759707/998/256/9"

                      units-per-pixel="0.00137329101562500000" order="9" />

             <TileSet href="http://c.tile.cloudmade.com/BC9A493B41014CAABB98F0471D759707/998/256/10"

                      units-per-pixel="0.00068664550781250000" order="10" />

             <TileSet href="http://c.tile.cloudmade.com/BC9A493B41014CAABB98F0471D759707/998/256/11"

                      units-per-pixel="0.00034332275390625000" order="11" />

             <TileSet href="http://c.tile.cloudmade.com/BC9A493B41014CAABB98F0471D759707/998/256/12"

                      units-per-pixel="0.00017166137695312500" order="12" />

             <TileSet href="http://c.tile.cloudmade.com/BC9A493B41014CAABB98F0471D759707/998/256/13"

                      units-per-pixel="0.00008583068847656250" order="13" />

             <TileSet href="http://c.tile.cloudmade.com/BC9A493B41014CAABB98F0471D759707/998/256/14"

                      units-per-pixel="0.00004291534423828125" order="14" />

             <TileSet href="http://c.tile.cloudmade.com/BC9A493B41014CAABB98F0471D759707/998/256/15"

                      units-per-pixel="0.00002145767211914062" order="15" />

             <TileSet href="http://c.tile.cloudmade.com/BC9A493B41014CAABB98F0471D759707/998/256/16"

                      units-per-pixel="0.00001072883605957031" order="16" />

             <TileSet href="http://c.tile.cloudmade.com/BC9A493B41014CAABB98F0471D759707/998/256/17"

                      units-per-pixel="0.00000536441802978516" order="17" />

             <TileSet href="http://c.tile.cloudmade.com/BC9A493B41014CAABB98F0471D759707/998/256/18"

                      units-per-pixel="0.00000268220901489258" order="18" />

             <TileSet href="http://c.tile.cloudmade.com/BC9A493B41014CAABB98F0471D759707/998/256/19"

                      units-per-pixel="0.00000134110450744629" order="19" />

          </TileSets>

          </TileMap>
```

And then you should find document of CloudMade tiles at [here](http://developers.cloudmade.com/projects/tiles/documents) to understand what **BC9A493B41014CAABB98F0471D759707/998/256** is.
Finally, to have your custom style loaded into ArcGIS, you can use Firebug on Firefox to inspect structure of the custom tiles. (! i have not used CloudMade for a long time so i dont remember whether CloudMade show you directly schema of custom tiles or not, but Firebug should work as i had a test).

The final step, writing another Cloudemade xml is not a big deal for you..i think.
Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have installed arcbrutile for arcgis 10, but I get the following error when requesting the cloudmade provider "error downloading document: please specify valid url" IT seems to occur with all dropbox urls

Comment: i think that caused by your internet as i still read the xml on dropbox well.

Comment: Ok...I finally got the extention working, but only with the 3 pre set styles which cloudmade offer. How do I link my own cloudmade map to ArcBruTile? I need to write my own xml which isn´t a problem, but I can´t see where I can link this xml file to the extention?!?!

Answer (score 0):

I was exactly that responding to your question @VietThanh Le gave the same solution which would i gave....neverthless i will sent it.

if you organize your folder scheme to TMS, you can add and see them in arcmap...

> ArcBruTile (arcbrutile.codeplex.com ) is an extension of ArcGIS which
>   uses the BruTile library to bring tiles into ArcGIS. This supports any
>   TMS/WMS-C service.
>
> ArcBruTile display maps from OpenStreetMap, Bing, SpatialCloud,
>   MapQuest, Europa Technologies, VR-TheWorld Online, Mapbox, Stamen
>   Design and others in ArcGIS Desktop.

and it also has maptiler support for geo-referenced file. you can get some information [here](http://arcbrutile.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ArcBruTile%20and%20MapTiler)...

beside this if you want to add your cloudmade map in ArcGIS API for JavaScript you should check out [this](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=16585) Extending TiledMapServiceLayer to add CloudMade Layer

> You can add CloudMade or any other tile based layer (like
>   OpenStreetMap) to your ArcGIS JS API application by extending
>   TiledMapServiceLayer.

i hope it helps you...